# Signed and Verify xml file in C#

Tags: c#

i am signing my xml File using
[Sign and Verify XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745.aspx)

but when i am signing in one machine and try to verify in other machine .

its failed . how can verify signed xml file in any other machine .

this is my code

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a new CspParameters object to specify 
            // a key container.
            CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
            cspParams.KeyContainerName = "XML_DSIG_RSA_KEY";

            // Create a new RSA signing key and save it in the container. 
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

            // Create a new XML document.
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            // Load an XML file into the XmlDocument object.
            xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            xmlDoc.Load(textBox1.Text);

            // Sign the XML document. 
            SignXml(xmlDoc, rsaKey);

            Console.WriteLine("XML file signed.");

            // Save the document.
            xmlDoc.Save(textBox1.Text);



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        //    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

     public static void SignXml(XmlDocument xmlDoc, RSA Key)
{
    // Check arguments. 
    if (xmlDoc == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("xmlDoc");
    if (Key == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Key");

    // Create a SignedXml object.
    SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);

    // Add the key to the SignedXml document.
    signedXml.SigningKey = Key;

    // Create a reference to be signed.
    Reference reference = new Reference();
    reference.Uri = "";

    // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
    XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
    reference.AddTransform(env);

    // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
    signedXml.AddReference(reference);

    // Compute the signature.
    signedXml.ComputeSignature();

    // Get the XML representation of the signature and save 
    // it to an XmlElement object.
    XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

    // Append the element to the XML document.
    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

}

     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         try
         {
             // Create a new CspParameters object to specify 
             // a key container.
             CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
             cspParams.KeyContainerName = "XML_DSIG_RSA_KEY";

             // Create a new RSA signing key and save it in the container. 
             RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

             // Create a new XML document.
             XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

             // Load an XML file into the XmlDocument object.
             xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
             xmlDoc.Load(textBox1.Text);

             // Verify the signature of the signed XML.
             Console.WriteLine("Verifying signature...");
             bool result = VerifyXml(xmlDoc, rsaKey);

             // Display the results of the signature verification to  
             // the console. 
             if (result)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("Verified");
             }
             else
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("Not Verified");
             }

         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            // Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
         }
     }

      // Verify the signature of an XML file against an asymmetric  
// algorithm and return the result. 
public static Boolean VerifyXml(XmlDocument Doc, RSA Key)
{
    // Check arguments. 
    if (Doc == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Doc");
    if (Key == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Key");

    // Create a new SignedXml object and pass it 
    // the XML document class.
    SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(Doc);

    // Find the "Signature" node and create a new 
    // XmlNodeList object.
    XmlNodeList nodeList = Doc.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");

    // Throw an exception if no signature was found. 
    if (nodeList.Count <= 0)
    {
        throw new CryptographicException("Verification failed: No Signature was found in the document.");
    }

    // This example only supports one signature for 
    // the entire XML document.  Throw an exception  
    // if more than one signature was found. 
    if (nodeList.Count >= 2)
    {
        throw new CryptographicException("Verification failed: More that one signature was found for the document.");
    }

    // Load the first <signature> node.  
    signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

    // Check the signature and return the result. 
    return signedXml.CheckSignature(Key);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to use the [CheckSignature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml.checksignature.aspx) method.

Comment: i added full code. its working in same machine , but when i am verify in other machine its failed .

Comment: what are the difference between the two machines ?

Comment: both have same configuration .